# Is it possible to do calculation in one textbox?

Tags: javascript, regex, textbox

I'm looking for something that I like to use for my project.
Like excel you can do a formula in a textbox.

I was wondering if this is also possible with javascript and regex?

Something like this should display the answer after pressing [ENTER]

[image: EXAMPLE]

This should display 25 after pressing enter.
Does anyone have a simple solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) like

```
$('input').keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13)
    {
        var result = eval($(this).val());
        $(this).val(result);
    }
});
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cjdb0vv8/3/)

Comment: that's not what i was looking for.

Comment: @theMaster, can you elaborate?

Comment: @theMaster, I have updated the answer and fiddle with what I think you wanted

Comment: sorry, I didn't use the jquery library on js fiddle your answer is good

Answer (score 0):

maybe this answer is helpful for you:

[How to use regular expression for calculator input with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24234265/how-to-use-regular-expression-for-calculator-input-with-javascript)

with this regex you can build a fairly simple calculator, but i would recommand it, like mentioned in the other question.