# How to prevent multilpe decimals and operators in simple calclulator app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I try to make calculator app using react and redux, everything is fine just have problem with multiply decimals and operators.
When I entry 8//2, 8**5, 3..5+6, I get errors. I just want to someone explaine me hot to prevent adding multiple decimals and operators, so it's only one is allowed.

Here is my reducer for caclulation.

```
import * as actionTypes from "../utils/actionTypes";
import * as operators from "../utils/actionTypes";

const initialState = {
  displayValue: "0",
  operator: null,
  previusNumber: 0
};

export const calculate = (displayValue, previusNumber, operator) => {
  switch (operator) {
    case operators.PLUS:
      return previusNumber + displayValue;
    case operators.SUBTRACT:
      return previusNumber - displayValue;
    case operators.MULTI:
      return previusNumber * displayValue;
    case operators.DIVIDE:
      return previusNumber / displayValue;
    default:
      return displayValue;
  }
};
const calculator = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.INPUT_NUMBER:
      return {
        ...state,
        displayValue:
          state.displayValue === "0"
            ? action.number.toString()
            : `${state.displayValue}${action.number}`
      };
    case actionTypes.INPUT_OPERATOR:
      return {
        displayValue: "0",
        operator: action.operator,
        previusNumber: state.operator
          ? calculate(
              parseFloat(state.displayValue),
              state.previusNumber,
              state.operator
            )
          : parseFloat(state.displayValue)
      };
    case actionTypes.INPUT_EQUAL:
      return {
        displayValue: calculate(
          parseFloat(state.displayValue),
          state.previusNumber,
          state.operator
        ).toString(),
        operator: null,
        previusNumber: 0
      };
    case actionTypes.CLEAR:
      return {
        displayValue: "0",
        operator: null,
        previusNumber: 0
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default calculator;
```

Comment: 1) are you sure you want to allow "+" "*" "/" "-" inside your input? You may allow only numbers and use buttons for actions
2) If you really want complex input you will probably need very good regexp. Try to look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24234265/how-to-use-regular-expression-for-calculator-input-with-javascript
3) but you will end up with complex solutions for double "("

Comment: Hello, I have separated buttons and operators, maybe you didn't understand me.When I click on 8 then operator / and again / then 2 I get error, I need to prevent multiple operators, so you can enter only 8/2.

Comment: In that case you should clear (first save input value somewhere) input after operator was clicked

Comment: I have previusNumber and displayValue

Comment: how you end up with multiple decimals or operators in that case? your `displayValue` should be a number

Comment: I don't know, yes displayValue is number https://imgur.com/a/8hViHA9

Comment: Please send your component code. Where you create your input and connect your reducer

Comment: Can I send you link from github?\

Comment: Send it. I'll check :)

Comment: https://github.com/BorislavkoDumic/Calculator/tree/cypresst

Comment: @Arseniy-II I'm sorry to bother you, did you have time to check?

Comment: I afraid I might have no time today to check. But I'll most certainly do it

Comment: Okay, just if you check please let me know, I need help .