# Simple Calculator implementing +,-,* and / in powerapps

Tags: powerapps-canvas

I have implemented a simple calculator with the basic mathematical operations +,-,* and /.

Below shown is my UI
[image]

The first text label is `label_Calculate` and below text label is `Calculator_Screen`

### This is my code snippet for the button `=`

[image]

### Below is my code block for `=` button

```
    UpdateContext({varCalculate:varCalculate&varNumber});
    
    Switch(varCalcType,
    "Plus",
    UpdateContext({varNumber:Text(Left(label_Calculate.Text,Len(label_Calculate.Text)-3)+Value(Calculator_Screen.Text))}),
    
    "Subtract",
    UpdateContext({varNumber:Text(Left(label_Calculate.Text,Len(label_Calculate.Text)-3)-Value(Calculator_Screen.Text))}),
    
    "Multiply",
    UpdateContext({varNumber:Text(Left(label_Calculate.Text,Len(label_Calculate.Text)-3)*Value(Calculator_Screen.Text))}),
    
    "Divide",
    UpdateContext({varNumber:Text(Left(label_Calculate.Text,Len(label_Calculate.Text)-3)/Value(Calculator_Screen.Text))}));
```

### Code for the Buttons 0-9

```
    If(
    varNumber = "0" || varToggle = true,
    UpdateContext({varNumber: "1"}),
    UpdateContext({varNumber: varNumber & 1})
);
    UpdateContext({varToggle: false})
```

### Code for the Button `+`

```
      UpdateContext({varCalculate:varNumber & " + "});
        UpdateContext({varToggle:true});
        UpdateContext({varCalcType:"Plus"})
```

Here I am able to only calculate single digit numbers and when my
input is 2-digit or 3-digit its giving me the following error.

```
The value '98 +' cannot be converted to a number
```

[image]

I tried changing the value `3` in the below code snippet to `4` then I
am able to perform 2-digit calculation. If changed to `5` then 5 digit calculation.

How can I make it to calculate a 10 digit number?

```
"Plus",

UpdateContext({varNumber:Text(Left(label_Calculate.Text,Len(label_Calculate.Text)-3)+Value(Calculator_Screen.Text))}),
```

Comment: Images are okay to show a user interface, but nobody is going to type in code from an image to test it. Please put the code into a code block so it can be cut and pasted, or examined more easily, if you want responses to your question.

Comment: ...[here is the reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), also see [ask]

Answer (score 1):

All in all, your troubles stem from trying to implement functionality that concerns **numbers**, but you are relying on **text**. You need to interpret the expressions

Issue 1: The operation is input as a text e.g. '39 + 2456'. When you are interpreting this expression, you use a static value (3) assuming that the second sumand is always 3 digits.

Issue 2: You use `Value()` and `Text()` for conversion. `Text()` is redundant since the Left() inside already returns a string. PowerApps gave you the error message for the  first sumand (left side of the exp.) because it is trying to implicitly convert it from text to number so they can be added. So, if you can validate your inputs to be numbers, you don't even need `Value()`.

What you could do is employ functions more suitable for this task. Using `Split()` you can isolate the sumands. `MatchAll()` could also validate the input for you, but a powerful RegEx expression could also be your key to handle multipart expressions with a mix of arithmetic operators.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-split

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-ismatch

[How to use regular expression for calculator input with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24234265/how-to-use-regular-expression-for-calculator-input-with-javascript)